# How can I move cursor over chart at any place and not just on the series data points?

Tags: javascript, charts, cursor, lineseries, lightningchart

I have 2 point line series each having default cursor on them. The default cursor runs along the series data (points). What I want is a cursor that I can move anywhere in the chart not just on the series data.

Comment: It's useful if you post a code sample in your question

Comment: That would depend on how you present the chart, could you please provide more details if possible or some parts of your code on how the chart is generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks for your question. Based on the tags, I'll assume you are using *LightningChart JS*.

If I understood your desired behaviour correctly, you'd like the cursor to always be positioned at the users mouse, and displaying the solved closest data-point in the result table.

This can be achieved with a *Chart Marker*, which is basically a cursor that can be created and positioned in application code.

[image: Custom cursor with ChartMarkerXY]

Here's a code snippet on how to:

- listen to mouse events on the document.
- solve nearest data-point from series.
- position Chart Marker at arbitrary location.

```js
const marker = chart.addChartMarkerXY()

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', ( event ) => {
    // Solve nearest data point.
    const cursorPoint = chart.solveNearest( { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY } )
    // Translate mouse location to Axis.
    const locationOnAxes = translatePoint(
        chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine( event.clientX, event.clientY ),
        chart.engine.scale,
        {
            x: chart.getDefaultAxisX().scale,
            y: chart.getDefaultAxisY().scale
        }
    )
    // Position Chart Marker, but override its location.
    marker
        .pointAt( cursorPoint )
        // Override Cursor location to that of mouse location.
        .setPosition( locationOnAxes )
} )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer with detailed explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if the chart occupies 100% of the browser window. In a nested chart with distance to the edge of the window the x and y values are shifted, even if the listener is directly on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a solution that also works in charts that are not fullscreen, the following may be helpful.

I added the following to get the current position of the element:

```
const elemLeftSpace = elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
const elemTopSpace = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

Make sure you call up the position in the listener, as they change as you scroll the page or resize the browser window.

After that you can calculate correct position:

```
const cursorPoint = chart.solveNearest( { x: event.clientX - elemLeftSpace, y: event.clientY - elemTopSpace } );
```

Complete code:

```
const marker = chart.addChartMarkerXY();
const elem = document.getElementById('chart-container');
    
elem.addEventListener( 'mousemove', ( event ) => {

    const elemLeftSpace = elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const elemTopSpace = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    // Solve nearest data point.
    const cursorPoint = chart.solveNearest( { x: event.clientX - elemLeftSpace, y: event.clientY - elemTopSpace } );

    if (cursorPoint) {
        const locationOnAxes = translatePoint(
            chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine( event.clientX, event.clientY ),
            chart.engine.scale,
            {
                x: chart.getDefaultAxisX().scale,
                y: chart.getDefaultAxisY().scale
            }
        );
        // Position Chart Marker, but override its location.
        marker
            .pointAt( cursorPoint )
            // Override Cursor location to that of mouse location.
            .setPosition( locationOnAxes );
})
```

Working example below:

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    AxisTickStrategies,
    DataPatterns,
    SolidLine,
    translatePoint,
    AutoCursorModes
} = lcjs

const containerId = 'chart-container';
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    containerId,
}).setAutoCursorMode(AutoCursorModes.disabled)

const axisX = chart.getDefaultAxisX()
const axisY = chart.getDefaultAxisY()
             
const data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  data[i] = {x: i, y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)};
}

const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries({
                  xAxis: axisX,
                  yAxis: axisY,
                  dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive

              })
            .setMouseInteractions(false);


lineSeries.add(data);


const marker = chart.addChartMarkerXY()
const elem = document.getElementById('chart-container');

elem.addEventListener( 'mousemove', ( event ) => {
    const elemLeftSpace = elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const elemTopSpace = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    // Solve nearest data point.
    const cursorPoint = chart.solveNearest( { x: event.clientX - elemLeftSpace, y: event.clientY - elemTopSpace } )
    // Translate mouse location to Axis.

    if (cursorPoint) {
        const locationOnAxes = translatePoint(
            chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine( event.clientX, event.clientY ),
            chart.engine.scale,
            {
                x: chart.getDefaultAxisX().scale,
                y: chart.getDefaultAxisY().scale
            }
        )
        // Position Chart Marker, but override its location.
        marker
            .pointAt( cursorPoint )
            // Override Cursor location to that of mouse location.
            .setPosition( locationOnAxes )
    }

} )
```

```css
.chart-container-wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
        
        
#chart-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-container-wrapper">
    <div id='chart-container'></div>
  </div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```